# How to send data from firebase php to arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266

***In the project I am working on***

> I want to send data to firebase going to arduino this specifically by
>   sending an information to change the wifi

***SSID***

***password***

> materials I used:

***esp8266-01***

***arduino uno r3***

***firebase***

***web server (000webhost)***

> code for arduino

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <DHT.h>;
SoftwareSerial Serial1(10, 11);
#define Trash "Trash3"
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
#define DHTPIN 2
#define TRIGGER_PIN 4
#define ECHO_PIN 3

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE, 11);

float humidity, temp_f;
int distance;
long duration;


String buff(64);
String getStr(128);

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial1.begin(9600);
  //Serial1.resetESP();
  delay(2000);
  Serial1.setTimeout(5000);

  dht.begin();
  pinMode(TRIGGER_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ECHO_PIN, INPUT);

  if (!connectWiFi()) {
    Serial.println("Can not connect to the WiFi.");
    while (true)
      ; // do nothing
  }
  Serial.println("OK, Connected to WiFi.");

  sendCommand("AT+CIPSTA?");
  //sendCommand("AT+CIPDNS_CUR?");
  sendCommand("AT+CIPSTAMAC?");

}

void loop() {

  temp_f = dht.readTemperature();
  humidity = dht.readHumidity();
  digitalWrite(TRIGGER_PIN, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TRIGGER_PIN, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIGGER_PIN, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(ECHO_PIN, HIGH);
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;

  // connect to server
  if (sendCommand("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"gg.com\",80")) {
    Serial.println("connected to Cloud");

    // build HTTP request
    getStr = "GET /upload.php?trash=";
    getStr += Trash;
    getStr += "&distance=";
    getStr += distance;
    getStr += "&temp_f=";
    getStr += temp_f;
    getStr += "&humidity=";
    getStr += humidity;
    getStr += " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    getStr += "Host: gg.com\r\n\r\n";

    // open send buffer
    buff = "AT+CIPSEND=";
    buff += getStr.length();
    if (sendCommand(buff.c_str()) && Serial1.find(">")) { // AT firmware is ready to accept data

      // send HTTP request
      Serial.println(getStr);
      Serial1.print(getStr);

      // print HTTP response
      if (Serial1.find("+IPD,")) { // response received
        int l = Serial1.parseInt();
        while (l > 0) {
          if (Serial1.available()) {
            Serial.write(Serial1.read());
            l--;
          }
        }
        Serial.println("--------------");
      } else {
        Serial.println("no response");
      }
    } else {
      Serial.println("send error");
    }
    sendCommand("AT+CIPCLOSE");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error connecting");
  }
}

bool connectWiFi() {

  if (!sendCommand("ATE0")) // echo off
    return false;
  if (!sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=0")) // set single connection mode
    return false;
  if (!sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1")) // set STA mode
    return false;
  return sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\"CAPSTONE\",\"capstonemis\"");
}

bool sendCommand(const char* cmd) {
  Serial.println(cmd);
  Serial1.println(cmd);
  while (true) {
    buff = Serial1.readStringUntil('\n');
    buff.trim();
    if (buff.length() > 0) {
      Serial.println(buff);
      if (buff == "OK" || buff == "SEND OK" || buff == "ALREADY CONNECTED")
        return true;
      if (buff == "ERROR" || buff == "FAIL" || buff == "SEND FAIL")
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

> code for firebase

```
<?php

require 'firebaseLib.php';
$Trash = $_GET["trash"];

$Distance = $_GET["distance"];
$Temperature = $_GET["temp_f"];
$Humidity= $_GET["humidity"];

// --- This is your Firebase URL
$baseURI = 'https://thesis1-69.firebaseio.com';
// --- Use your token from Firebase here
$token = 'gg';
// --- Here is your parameter from the http GET



$devicestatus= array('Distance' => $Distance,'Temperature' => $Temperature,'Humidity' => $Humidity);

$firebasePath = '/thesis1-69/';




$full= array($Trash => $devicestatus);

/// --- Making calls
$fb = new Firebase($baseURI, $token);
$fb -> update($firebasePath, $full);


?>
```

any  guide and help can help me a lot
thank you so much :)

Comment: this is code from my chat with Xiaomy https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85432/discussion-on-question-by-xiaomy-arduino-uno-with-esp8266-01-with-at

Comment: yeah I am xiaomy

Comment: @Juraj can we create a chat?

Comment: why as new user?

Comment: I can't reply on the conversation and can't post new question in the recent account

Comment: we made an error in this code. change `String buff(64); String getStr(128);` to `String buff; String getStr;` and add  `buff.reserve(64);  getStr.reserve(256);` as first in setup()

Comment: no need to add some code on the PHP?

Comment: is this right sir?

void setup() {
buff.reserve(64);
getStr.reserve(256);
  Serial.begin(9600);

Comment: I just wanna change the wifi through POST so I want to used it
I will send data to firebase then will received by the arduino

Comment: good morning sir

thank you sir

can you provide me an example of receiving the information back to arduino

I just want to change the SSID & password of arduino (esp-01) by using an app
that app uses the firebase to send data to web server back to arduino
so the wifi will be change

then no need to manually code it by using arduino IDE

Comment: it would be better to return the new ssid and password as a response of the existing request, which sends sensor data. of course only if the wifi should reconnect

Comment: so I will use the POST?

Comment: POST request is different from GET request only in one thing: it can send data in the 'body'. as you can see in my answer the data send are not in the URL, but after the request header. the response format is same for GET and POST

Comment: ah sorry about that
thank you for the right idea sir :)

but how can I get what I want?

Comment: so it will be depending on the arduino code or firebase php?

Comment: first in php add the response if the ssid should change. the Arduino sketch as it is  now prints the received response. then you can ask how to parse and process it

Comment: so likely GET request too?

Comment: I just thought to make a variable but I don't know how the firebase data will be receive by the web server

Comment: add a response to the GET request which delivers the sensor data

Comment: same format with the trash?

Comment: the GET request you have, can return the new ssid and password

Comment: I'll set 2 variables?

I don't know how can I make it
because GET request is used by the arduino to send data from web server to firebase to app

Comment: and the new ssid should be retrieved from somewhere else? not over the php page?

Comment: the app is connected to firebase
so the firebase will received the ssid and password
set by the user that use the app

Comment: I think php page will be a gateway between the arduino and firebase

Comment: so the php page can return the new ssid and password as a response to the GET request it received with the sensor data.

Comment: yes sir
I think

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94390/discussion-on-question-by-mark-anthony-donadillo-how-to-send-data-from-firebase).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add global variable `String data;` and in loop()

```
data = "trash=";
data += Trash;
data += "&distance=";
data += distance;
data += "&temp_f=";
data += temp_f;
data += "&humidity=";
data += humidity;

// build HTTP request
getStr = "POST /upload.php HTTP/1.1\r\n";
getStr += "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
getStr += "Content-length: ";
getStr += data.length();
getStr += "\r\nHost: gg.com\r\n\r\n";
getStr += data;
```

Comment: Thank you sir
so the data, it represents SSID and password?

Comment: I wanna keep both the GET and POST

Comment: for example
I will set variable namely data1 and data2
then on the 

return sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\"CAPSTONE\",\"capstonemis\"");
}

will be replace

return sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=\"data1\",\"data2\"");
}

is this right sir?

Comment: I don't need to add some PHP code on the website server?

Comment: so you want to "get" data. why do you want to do it with a "post" request?

Comment: ah it doesn't need a "post" request to get data from firebase/web server?
I got the wrong idea on using "post"
I thought it was for receiving data from firebase to arduino

I will change the wifi of arduino (esp8266-01) by using an app
that app send data to firebase then it will send data(SSID & password) to arduino